# How do I name a mimemail-message.tpl.php template to be used with a specific webform?

Tags: 7, theming, webforms, mimemail

I cant seem to get the naming of the `mimemail-message.tpl.php` correct in Drupal 7. I know the naming scheme says `"mimemail-message--[module]--[key].tpl.php"` but either I'm not understanding what the brackets represent or I'm doing something else wrong.

I've tried:

```
mimemail-message--webform--mywebformname.tpl.php
mimemail-message--webform--250.tpl.php
```

Just `mimemail-message.tpl.php` works, but I need different template layout depending on which webform is used.

Also, is mime mail not supposed to make use of `webform-mail-250.tpl.php` at all?

Comment: i guess the `[module]` mean the module implement the `hook_mail` if you have any other module implements  `hook_mail` `[module]` will be the machine name of this module instead of `webform`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As you can see in [line 264 of webform.submissions.inc](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/7.x-4.x/includes/webform.submissions.inc#L264) Webform uses `submission` as the key.

Thus it needs to be named

```
mimemail-message--webform--submission.tpl.php
```

There is no way to target a specific webform without some extra custom code work.

**mymodule.module**

```
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['module'] == 'webform') {
    $nid = $message['params']['node']->nid;
    $message['key'] = $nid; // set key to nid
  }
}
```

Now you can do

```
mimemail-message--webform--250.tpl.php
```